# appengine phpmyadmin deploy error 400

Tags: php, google-app-engine, deployment, error-handling, phpmyadmin

I'm having trouble to deploy phpmyadmin with google app engine launcher.
I have followed the google cloud tutorial but when I deploy, this is the log:

```
2015-11-10 17:21:50 Running command: "['C:\\Python27\\pythonw.exe', '-u',                 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\google_appengine\\appcfg.py', '--    oauth2_credential_file=C:\\Users\\Hernan/.appcfg_oauth2_tokens', 'update', u'D:\\phpMyAdmin']"
05:21 PM Application: nobisagro2015; module: phpmyadmin; version: 1
05:21 PM Host: appengine.google.com
05:21 PM 
Starting update of app: nobisagro2015, module: phpmyadmin, version: 1
05:21 PM Getting current resource limits.
05:21 PM Scanning files on local disk.
05:21 PM Scanned 500 files.
05:21 PM Scanned 1000 files.
05:21 PM Scanned 1500 files.
05:21 PM Scanned 2000 files.
05:21 PM Cloning 1077 static files.
05:22 PM Cloning 2161 application files.
05:22 PM Cloned 2000 files.
05:22 PM Uploading 1 files and blobs.
05:22 PM Uploaded 1 files and blobs.
05:22 PM Compilation starting.
05:22 PM Compilation completed.
05:22 PM Starting deployment.
05:22 PM Rolling back the update.
Error 400: --- begin server output ---

Client Error (400)
The request is invalid for an unspecified reason.
--- end server output ---
2015-11-10 17:22:20 (Process exited with code 1)

You can close this window now.
```

The files app.yaml and config.inc.php are right, as the tutorial says. I've read similar questions and usually is a problem with the application ID, but is not my case.

Here's app.yaml:

```
application: nobisagro2015
version: 1
module: phpmyadmin
runtime: php55
api_version: 1

handlers:

- url: /(.*\.(ico$|jpg$|png$|gif$))
  static_files: \1
  upload: (.*\.(ico$|jpg$|png$|gif$))
  application_readable: true

- url: /(.*\.(htm$|html$|css$|js$))
  static_files: \1
  upload: (.*\.(htm$|html$|css$|js$))
  application_readable: true

- url: /(.*\.(php$))
  script: \1
  login: admin

- url: /(.+)
  script: index.php
  login: admin

- url: /.*
  script: index.php
  login: admin
```

I don't know what the problem is... any help?

Thanks!!!

Comment: It looks like this can happen for a number of reasons (encoding, file locations, app-id etc). I'd start by removing all handlers except one, and then add them back one at time in increasing order of complexity until you hit the error again on deployment to at least narrow it down.

Comment: Thanks, finally I decided to erase everything, download phpmyadmin project again and deploy it again. After the second time of doing that, it worked...